# Basic Locally Hosted Web-server Functionality

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, webserver

I am working on an addition to a project to create dynamic HTML reports from data that is stored in a SQLite database. Initially, I tried to do everything client-side using things like [browserify](http://browserify.org/) and [sql.js](https://github.com/kripken/sql.js/), but I ran into a lot of issues trying to read from the .db file locally.

For that reason, I have now decided to spin up a very basic web server that will be locally hosted. Essentially, I want the user to be able to navigate to http://localhost:3000 and hit a landing page which is the home page of the report.

I have set up a very basic HTTP server using express with the following code running in node:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

This works fine, and exposes the /public directory on port 3000, which has a placeholder index.html as of right now. My problem is, that when I try to start adding my code that reads from the SQLite database, none of the necessary require() functions work (specifically, require('fs'), due to it not being defined.

At a basic level, my question boils down to this:

How can i have the ability to read from the SQLite database file in the HTML/Javascript pages that live on the webserver? Whenever I try to use the necessary functions, it tells me that require() is not defined, or other similar errors.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I suspect that you are using require in client side code. That is not gonna work.

Comment: I think that is my problem as well, I guess my question then remains, how can I serve up data from the SQLite database file using server-side code, but display this on HTML pages (tables, specifically), that the client will see. I have the necessary code to pull from the SQLite database sitting on the server, and it works fine - how do I display that data on the HTML pages?

Comment: Well you need some routes to serve the data and some way to get the data from the server to client. Something like app.get('/users',function(req,res,next){res.json({<your-user-data-here>})}) and on client you can use jQuery like this $.get('/users',function(data){alert(data)});

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So what I gather from your response is that I essentially can set up a function that, when another page requests the specific URL (in your example /users), the server will return that data in JSON format? Javascript is not my forte so I'm kind of learning it as I go here. Thanks again!

Comment: You can return the data in any format you like, be it json, XML or even prerendered HTML code that you would insert into page. It was just an example with json.

Comment: I adapted your example and it's working perfectly for what I need, thanks a bunch!